# PHP URL Parameters and GET commands - issue with second command

Tags: php

is this the best way to put 2 values in the URL and then get them back on the next page.

im currently having an issue with the second value not being populated

URL: `http://test.com/Physiotoinstruction.php?PhysioReference=100661&a‌​mp;Reference=456789`

```
echo "<td><a href=\"Physiotoinstruction.php?PhysioReference={$search_rs['PhysioReference']}&a‌​mp;Reference={$Reference}\"‌​>Select</a></td>";

$reference1=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['PhysioReference']);
$reference2=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['Reference']);
```

Comment: Should work, as long as you just use & and not &amp;

Comment: @ErikL so i just need to remove amp;

Comment: You should also urlencode the values before you insert them into the URL, unless you're absolutely, positively sure that they'll never have any unusual characters in them.

Comment: yes, that should be it, make the url look like this: http://test.com/Physiotoinstruction.php?PhysioReference=100661&Reference=456789